# Qutebrowser Searchengine Script

Tags: bash

[Qutebrowser](https://qutebrowser.org) uses search engines similar to [DuckDuckGo's Bangs](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) to facilitate searching.
The `config.py` file for the browser contains a search engine Python dictionary.
Each key is a search engine, and the corresponding value is a template string.
When a search engine is used, every `{}` in its template is replaced by the search term, and the resulting url is visited.

A dictionary with identical keys can be defined anywhere in `config.py`, so it's important for me to get only the key-value pairs in the `c.url.searchengines` dictionary.
The relevant section of my `config.py` looks like this:

```
## Search engines which can be used via the address bar. Maps a search
## engine name (such as `DEFAULT`, or `ddg`) to a URL with a `{}`
## placeholder. The placeholder will be replaced by the search term, use
## `{{` and `}}` for literal `{`/`}` signs. The search engine named
## `DEFAULT` is used when `url.auto_search` is turned on and something
## else than a URL was entered to be opened. Other search engines can be
## used by prepending the search engine name to the search term, e.g.
## `:open google qutebrowser`.
## Type: Dict
# c.url.searchengines = {'DEFAULT': 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q={}'}
c.url.searchengines = {
                       'DEFAULT': 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q={}',
                       'ddg'    : 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q={}',
                       'gh'     : 'https://github.com/search?q={}',
                       'w'      : 'https://en.wikipedia.org/?search={}',
                       }

## Page(s) to open at the start.
```

I wrote this script to mimic the behavior of Qutebrowser's search engines in the terminal:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

search_engine_file="$HOME/.config/qutebrowser/config.py"
search_engine_start="c.url.searchengines = {"

# use $1 if available; otherwise use default search engine
search_engine=${1:-"DEFAULT"}
# rest of the arguments are the search term.
search_term="${@:2}"

# add surrounding single quotes if not there
if [[ $search_engine != "'*" ]]; then
    search_engine="'$search_engine"
fi
if [[ $search_engine != "*'" ]]; then
    search_engine="$search_engine'"
fi

# get lines after start of search engines until empty line
raw_search_engines=$(awk "/$search_engine_start/,/^$/" $search_engine_file)

if [[ $raw_search_engines == *$search_engine* ]]; then
    # get lines containing the search engine in single quotes
    search_engine_lines=$(echo "$raw_search_engines" | grep $search_engine)

    # isolate line with search engine definition
    definition=$(echo "$search_engine_lines" | grep --basic-regexp ',$')

    # extract template from single quotes
    template=$(echo $definition | awk --field-separator "'" '{print $4}')

else
    echo >&2 Search engine not found.
    exit 1
fi

# print template if no search term is given
if [[ -z $search_term ]]; then
    echo $template
    exit 0
fi

# replace all {}'s with search term
echo $template | sed "s/{}/$search_term/g"
```

I'm not familiar with code style conventions and best practices in Bash scripts.
`sed` and `awk` look very powerful, but I don't know when their use is appropriate.
I also want to know how I can change the script to be POSIX-compliant.

Any suggestions for improving my script are very welcome.